# Pull back specific post codes from table in SQL

Tags: sql, database, pattern-matching, sql-server-2016, postal-code

I'm having an issue in selecting specific post codes.

These are all valid UK post code formats:

1. WV11JX
2. WV1 1JX
3. WV102QK
4. WV10 2QK
5. WV113KQ
6. WV11 3KQ

Now, say I had a mix of the above formats in the data table; I'm trying to select only post codes that conform to the WV1 prefix (in this example).

In the above 6 item list, I'd want to return:

- WV11JX
- WV1 1JX

I would want to exclude:

- WV102QK
- WV10 2QK
- WV113KQ
- WV11 3KQ

If I execute the following query this will bring back both the `WV11`'s and the `WV1`'s:

```
SELECT ad.PostCode,*
FROM Staff st
INNER JOIN Address ad on ad.AddressID = st.Address
WHERE
ad.PostCode like 'WV1%'
```

Changing the condition in the `WHERE` to cater for length like this doesn't really work either:

```
SELECT ad.PostCode,*
FROM Staff st
INNER JOIN Address ad on ad.AddressID = st.Address
WHERE
(
ad.PostCode like 'WV1%'
OR
(ad.PostCode like 'WV1%' and LEN(ad.PostCode) = 6)
```

The above will just filter out any of the formats with a space so if we cater for those by doing the below:

```
SELECT ad.PostCode,*
FROM Staff st
INNER JOIN Address ad on ad.AddressID = st.Address
WHERE
(ad.PostCode like 'WV1%' and LEN(ad.PostCode) = 6)
or
(ad.PostCode like 'WV1 %' and LEN(ad.PostCode) = 7)
```

That fixes the issue but the problem is that we want to check more than just the 'WV1' prefix in this manner so having a growing list of 'OR' comparisons isn't viable.

How do we isolate the above post codes in a scalable way?
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Worth noting that *technically* a UK postcode is supposed to have a white space before the last 3 characters. So `'WV10JQK'` doesn't fully conform. Wikipedia actually has a [REGEX string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Formatting) for validation for them.

Comment: Actually, none of those postcodes are valid UK postcodes... UK Postcodes end with `[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]`; all you yours end with `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]`. They look more like UK number plates than Postcodes. `'WV11AKQ'` would represent a vehicle constructed in H1 2011 in Bristol. The sector character of a UK Postcode (3rd character from the right/after the white space) is **always** a numerical value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
WHERE ad.PostCode like 'WV1 [0-9][A-Z][A-Z]' OR
      ad.PostCode like 'WV1[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]'
```

I'm not sure if numbers are allowed for the last three characters.

Comment: I've corrected the initial 2 here, as the OP has now supplied valid postcodes. Your last one won't work any more, however, Gordon; but it would have based on the OP's original (incorrect) data.

Comment: @Larnu chill out with your passive aggressive comments mate..

Comment: @Sanguine . . . Larnu's comment was helpful and very reasonable.  I see nothing negative about it.  Larnu also did me the favor of fixing the answer.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff .